# Nodejs and typescript cannot find connect-mongodb-session types in production on heroku

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, heroku

I am using Node.js with TypeScript and deploy it on Heroku. I set up the `connect-mongodb-session` module, set the store, and deploy it.

```
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       
       added 323 packages, and audited 324 packages in 13s
       
       24 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       npm notice 
       npm notice New major version of npm available! 9.5.1 -> 10.0.0
       npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.0.0>
       npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.0.0` to update!
       npm notice 
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > server@1.0.0 build
       > npm install && npm run build-dev
       
       
       up to date, audited 320 packages in 621ms
       
       24 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
       > server@1.0.0 build-dev
       > npx tsc
       
       src/app.ts(10,26): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'connect-mongodb-session'. '/tmp/build_78f240a8/node_modules/connect-mongodb-session/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
         Try `npm i --save-dev @types/connect-mongodb-session` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'connect-mongodb-session';`
       src/passport/passport.ts(3,46): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'passport-facebook'. '/tmp/build_78f240a8/node_modules/passport-facebook/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
         Try `npm i --save-dev @types/passport-facebook` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'passport-facebook';`
       src/passport/passport.ts(63,69): error TS7006: Parameter 'done' implicitly has an 'any' type.
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

The app.ts cookies and sessions setup:

```
import MongoDBStore from "connect-mongodb-session";
const mongoStore = MongoDBStore(session);
import { mongoURI } from './database/connection';
import ConnectMongoDBSession from 'connect-mongodb-session';


const store = new mongoStore({
    collection: "sessions",
    uri: mongoURI,
    expires: 1000,
  }) as ConnectMongoDBSession.MongoDBStore;


app.use(cors({ 
    origin: getProductionURL(), 
    credentials: true}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(session({ 
    secret: 'secretcode',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store: store,
    cookie: {
        sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'none' : 'lax',
        maxAge: 48 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 48 hours
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        httpOnly: true
    }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

My TSconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

My passport JSON:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/connect-mongodb-session": "^2.4.5",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "^20.5.9",
    "@types/passport-facebook": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.7",
    "@types/express-validator": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.12",
    "@types/passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.11",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.35",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "connect-mongo": "^5.0.0",
    "connect-mongodb-session": "^3.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "express-validator": "^7.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^7.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^3.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-passwordless": "^0.0.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

In development, everything works. But in production nothing working... I added some modifications with the help of ChatGPT, but at a point it become useless.

Comment: ChatGPT is _not intelligent_. Don't trust anything it says.

Comment: The first error block says "build failed". Is this a build-time error that occurs when you deploy? Please [edit] that code block and add _all_ of the errors.

Comment: Thank you. I added all the error log. Yes. It is build time error when occurs when I deploy. Should I add also my passport configuration?

Comment: Is this because the types and the modules are listed in dependencies and the module is in devDependencies?

Comment: also, chatgpt tells me to Update with this:`import MongoDBStore from "connect-mongodb-session";
const mongoStore = MongoDBStore(session);



/**
 *      Import routes
 *          -> user router
*/
import userRouter from './router/user/user.router';
import { mongoURI } from './database/connection';
import ConnectMongoDBSession from 'connect-mongodb-session';


const store = new mongoStore({
    collection: "sessions",
    uri: mongoURI,
    expires: 1000,
  }) as ConnectMongoDBSession.MongoDBStore;`. But this do nothing. same errors

Comment: _Again_, don't trust ChatGPT. It spews words, but it doesn't understand them.

Comment: Is the thing you've got labeled as your "passport JSON" actually your `package.json`? It's not complete. Please [edit] to add the whole file. Or at the very least, include your `scripts`.

Comment: Hi. I found a sollution. I dont know how a good practice would be. In the src directory I created two folders : passport-facebook.d.ts and connect-mongodb-session.d.ts. and declared the modules like : `declare module 'passport-facebook';
` How is this solving?